# Rendering data from a query result in data table in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have a database table which contains answers given to a set of questions by a set of people(reviewer's) means there are m*n(no. of questions * no. of people) records which I am fetching using a normal select query. Now that I have a list of that entity(entity class of database table) objects I want to show the result on xhtml page in following format:
1. First column shows all the distinct questions.
2. Rest of the column header are the names of the people who answered it.
3. Rest data should be the answer given by a particular reviewer against a particular question.

How to achieve this in primefaces? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces `<p:dataTable>` can handle dynamic columns using `<p:columns>`. Check the documentation at [Primefaces](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) under DataTable -> Dynamic Columns.

You need two things:

1. Create a `List<String> columns`, with content like `{"Question", "Peter", "Thomas", "Andrew", ...}`,
2. Create a `List<String[]> answers` where the `String[]` array will have same size as the number of your respondents + 1 and will contain at index 0 text of the question followed with your user answers: `{"What is your PIN number?", "1234", "1122","2211",...}`. Be careful to maintain answer and user order.

Your table will then look like this in a JSF page:

```
<p:dataTable var="answer" value="#{fooBean.answers}">
   <p:columns var="columnName" value="#{fooBean.columns}" columnIndexVar="columnNumber">
      <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="#{columnName}" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{answer[columnNumber]}" />
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks for that klimpond!! Yes i have used <p:columns> but somehow I am not able to implement my thing using it. If you can help me with my problem statement then most appreciated.

Comment: Yepp!! Thanks man once again! Actually i have resolved my problem. But the one you have provided looks more efficient so will try and implement it.